# shouldStartLoadWithRequest not being called when clicking on external links in local file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am loading a local file:

```
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                          pathForResource:@"about" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

And trying to open any external links within this file, in safari using the following:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = [request URL];
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"http"] || [[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"https"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
} else
return YES;
}
```

but this never gets called. Reading up I can see that shouldStartLoadWithRequest wouldn't get called by a local file but when opening an external link this should then be called?

---

Adding 
    web.delegate = self;

to viewDidLoad fixed it. Whoops

Comment: have u assigned the delegate?

Comment: Nope, works now :) (plus I feel rather stupid!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that you assigned a delegate and check that if your delegate is a uiviewcontroller that is still retained.